# How do I use a Rails ActiveRecord migration to insert a primary key into a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, primary-key

I need to create an AR migration for a table of image files.  The images are being checked into the source tree, and should act like attachment_fu files.  That being the case, I'm creating a hierarchy for them under /public/system.

Because of the way attachment_fu generates links, I need to use the directory naming convention to insert primary key values.  How do I override the auto-increment in MySQL as well as any Rails magic so that I can do something like this:

```
image = Image.create(:id => 42, :filename => "foo.jpg")
image.id #=> 42
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yikes, not a pleasant problem to have. The least-kludgy way I can think of to do it is to have some code in your migration that actually "uploads" all the files through attachment-fu, and therefore lets the plugin create the IDs and place the files.

Something like this:

```
Dir.glob("/images/to/import/*.{jpg,png,gif}").each do |path|

  # simulate uploading the image
  tempfile = Tempfile.new(path)
  tempfile.set_encoding(Encoding::BINARY) if tempfile.respond_to?(:set_encoding)
  tempfile.binmode
  FileUtils.copy_file(path, tempfile.path)

  # create as you do in the controller - may need other metadata here
  image = Image.create({:uploaded_data => tempfile})
  unless image.save
    logger.info "Failed to save image #{path} in migration: #{image.errors.full_messages}"
  end

  tempfile.close!
end
```

A look at attachment-fu's tests might be useful.

Comment: I didn't do this, but I think this is the right way to do it... let the code do it's thing and don't try to subvert it.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike, say Sybase, in MySQL if you specify the id column in the insert statement's column list, you can insert any valid, non-duplicate value in the id. No need to do something special.

I suspect the rails magic is just to not let rails know the id is auto-increment. If this is the only way you'll be inserting into this table, then *don't* make the id auto_increment. Just make in an int not null primary key.

Though frankly, this is using a key as data, and so it makes me uneasy. If attachment_fu is just looking for a *column* named "id", make a column named id that's really data, and make a column named "actual_id" the actual, synthetic, auto_incremented key.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the time to replace attachment_fu. I'd agree that using the primary key field to construct a filepath is a little iffy.

Answer (score 1):

```
image = Image.create(:filename => "foo.jpg") { |r| r.id = 42 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my kluge:

```
class AddImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    Image.destroy_all

    execute("ALTER TABLE images AUTO_INCREMENT = 1")

    image = Image.create(:filename => "foo.jpg")
    image.id #=> 1
  end

  def self.down
  end
end
```

Comment: This looks to do exactly what the default primary key does... what's the difference in functionality?

Comment: The create() method doesn't use the value of ":id => ##" if it's given.  While I used the kluge above, I think the right answer is to let the AR class do it work, as @Sarah Mei suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand why you need to do this, but if you only need to do this a single time, for a migration, just use `execute` in the migration to set the ID (assuming it's not already taken, which I can't imagine it would be):

> execute "INSERT INTO images (id, filename) VALUES (42, 'foo.jpg')"

Answer (score 0):

I agree with AdminMyServer although I believe you can still perform this task on the object directly:

`image = Image.new :filename => "foo.jpg"

image.id = 42

image.save`

You'll also need to ensure your id auto-increment is updated at the end of the process to avoid clashes in the future.

`newValue = Images.find(:first, :order => 'id DESC').id + 1

execute("ALTER TABLE images AUTO_INCREMENT = #{newValue}")`

Hope this helps.